# Sql query insert hex string into varbinary(max) gives wrong results

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

With the following sql query I will get the wrong input into my database (Microsoft SQL Server 2008) table:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[test]([ExampleWorking],[ExampleWrong])VALUES(0xFF, 0xFFFF)
```

whereas ExampleWorking & ExampleWrong are both VARBINARY(max)

The result in the database is:

ExampleWorking = 0xFF
ExampleWrong = 0x3F (I was expecting 0xFFFF here)

What do I miss here?
I'm new to SQL and it's data types though.

Comment: schema..............

Comment: Can't reproduce: I created a test table with two `VARBINARY(max)` columns, inserted `0xFF, 0xFFFF`. Doing a `SELECT` then gave back `0xFF, 0xFFFF`.

Comment: `DECLARE @T TABLE([ExampleWorking] VARBINARY(MAX), [ExampleWrong] VARBINARY(MAX)); INSERT INTO @T([ExampleWorking],[ExampleWrong])VALUES(0xFF, 0xFFFF); SELECT * FROM @T`. Check if you have a trigger or other intriguing logic on `ExampleWrong`, or else if your logic for getting back the values is correct.

Comment: For some reason, I get error "Invalid object name 'dbo.test'" when I run your script.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
    declare @varbinary varbinary(max), @hax varchar(max)
--   you can also cast hax to string or varbinary in this way
    set @hax = '0xFFFF'
    select @hax
    select @varbinary  = cast(@hax  as varbinary(max) )
    select  @varbinary 
    select cast(@varbinary   as varchar(max) )
```

Comment: So I would query:
INSERT INTO [dbo].[test]([ExampleWorking],[ExampleWrong])VALUES(CAST('0xFF' as varbinary(max)), CAST('0xFFFF' as varbinary(max))) ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I actually solved the problem. It was an issue with HeidiSQL not displaying the content right. So there was actually written 0xFFFF in the database but HeidiSQL (for whatever reason) showed me 0x3F in the data table view...

I was actually to lazy to query for it in HeidiSQL, but after I did, it showed me "yy" .. then after a double click it changed to 0xFFFF .....

Anyway, enjoy your day and thanks for the quick replies!

Cheers!

Comment: It showed `ÿ`, most likely -- `U+00FF LATIN SMALL LETTER Y WITH DIAERESIS`. `0x3F` is, of course, the ASCII value of the question mark (`?`), and that may be a fallback for `U+FFFF`, which is not a Unicode character.  I'm guessing the code has *issues* with decoding data that should not be decoded.